# How to Pinch/Scale uniformly with an edge constraint (Blender 2.8)

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms

I'm wondering if it's possible to scale or 'pinch' 2 parallel vertices uniformly with an 'edge' constraint.

It seems I can select 2 vertices, and use the 'Edge Slide' tool which definitely keeps them constrained along an edge. However, this only allows movement along a single axis, whereas I'd like to be able to use the Scale tool to pinch them towards, or away from each other.

I would do this in 3DSMax quite often as I could come back to my support edge loops at any time of the modeling process, and then quickly adjust them uniformly.

Here's a quick picture to help illustrate (I hope!)

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!